# HTML - Alternative to having an id as a number?

Tags: html

I wanted to get some input on how to best handle my situation.

I want to store a numerical id for each table row(< tr>) but I realize that it isn't good practice to make an id for the < tr> a number.  Is there any other way to store an id/number value for a table row besides storing the id as a column field?

Basically when you click on the table row it will take you to another page that loads data from a database depending on the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "not good practice"; it's not actually illegal unless you are using HTML5, which is more permissive. For compatibility reasons, however, you should not start ids with numbers.

You have two choices: Custom data attributes, or custom attributes. The earlier is preferred, as the latter produces invalid HTML. For example:

```
<tr customattribute="1"> <!-- not a good idea -->
<tr data-custom-attr="1"> <!-- Better idea/preferred way -->
```

You will have to access both via JavaScript. If you are using jQuery, for example:

```
$('selector').data('custom-attr');
```

Comment: The `customattribute` thing isn't valid HTML, though. This is what `data-*` was created for

Comment: That is true. I've modified my answer to make not of that.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input.  I feel silly for not knowing about the data-custom attribute.

Comment: Why have you stated "ids can not start with numbers", linking to the part of the spec that clearly says that they can?

Comment: @Alohci I linked to the wrong spec. Id names could not start with numbers until HTML5 came about. HTML5 has a more permissive spec.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `data-`. As in `<tr data-name="1">`

Answer (score 2):

My be see on [HTML data-* Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp). For you example:

```
<tr data-id="1"> </tr>
<tr data-id="2"> </tr>
......................
<tr data-id="N"> </tr>
```

Access by jQuery (simple):

```
$('tr').each(function(){
   var id = $(this).data('id');
   //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 `data-*` attribute to store relevant data to your element. So in your case, it should be like this:

```
<tr data-id="6"> .. </tr>
```

You can use [getAttribute API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) to get the id of the row when it is clicked like this

```
var id = parseInt(clickedRow.getAttribute('data-id'), 10);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store the number in a hidden td.

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr><td class='hideme'>123</td><td>Visible stuff</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='hideme'>124</td><td>Visible stuff</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='hideme'>125</td><td>Visible stuff</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.hideme {
  display: none;
}
```

You click on a row, find the number with a jQuery .find, and pass that number to a script.

Or you could use the jQuery .data() statement and have numbers associated with specific rows or tds.
On "click" of the specific element, you read the data statement and pass it to a script.

And I'll bet there are many other ways to handle this.